# DLL File can not add the C# project

Tags: c#, dll, sdk

I have HikVistion Finger print device, and SDK there are dll files,
When I add the DLL file it's getting this error massage,

if you have a solution for this please share with me,

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: E: it local drive or usb ?

Comment: it's local.. and connect to ethernet cable.

Answer (score 0):

try to run from cmd the command:

```
TlbImp.exe HCNetSDK.dll
```

it should create a valid dll for you.

> TlbImp location : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

**Tlbimp.exe (Type Library Importer)**

The Type Library Importer converts the type definitions found within a COM type library into equivalent definitions in a common language runtime assembly. The output of Tlbimp.exe is a binary file (an assembly) that contains runtime metadata for the types defined within the original type library. You can examine this file with tools such as Ildasm.exe.
This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio. To run the tool, use the Developer Command Prompt (or the Visual Studio Command Prompt in Windows 7). For more information, see Command Prompts.

- If its not helping try to look if you have assembly dependency that your dll looks for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's not work.. I'll check assembly dependency